# Dereferencing array in a subroutine

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I am trying to pass an array and a scalar to a subroutine. But there seems to be a problem with array dereferencing. Below is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr=("95,100", "102,65", "92,34");
my $len=100;

avg($len,\@arr);

sub avg{
     my $len = shift;
     my $array=@_;
     my @new=@{$array};
     print @new,"\n";
  }
```

The print statement prints this warning:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test_arr.pl line 13.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use an array in scalar context, the array returns the number of elements in it.

So when you say

```
my $array = @_;
```

The value of `$array` is the number 1, because `@_` has one thing in it. (You already `shift`ed the first scalar off.)

So to fix that, you could do

```
sub avg { 
    my $len = shift;
    my $array_ref = shift;

    my @new = @$array_ref;
    ...
}
```

Or you could use a parallel list assignment

```
sub avg { 
    my ( $len, $array_ref ) = @_;
    ...
```

Or you could just yank the reference out of `@_` directly

```
sub avg { 
    my $len = shift;
    my @new = @{ $_[0] };
    ...
```

I like the middle option.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ("95,100", "102,65", "92,34");
my $len = 100;

avg($len, \@arr);

sub avg{
    my $len = shift;
    my $array = $_[0]; # Pass the 2nd element of original argument list
                       # which is now the 1st element of the argument list
                       # (which is a reference to @arr), not the list itself.
     my @new = @{$array};
     print @new, "\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`my $array=@_;` is not correct, you should use `my $array=shift;` or combine and use `my ($len, $array) = @_;`.

You have obtained a scalar value of `@_` (i.e., the number of elements within it) by saying `$array=@_;`.